# Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ be a measure space. Show that for disjoint $A_1, A_2, \dots$ $\lim_{n \to \infty }\nu(A_n) =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \nu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that the measure of $X$ is bounded. Show that for disjoint $A_1, A_2, \dots$ $\lim_{n \to \infty }\nu(A_n) =0$.

Since $X$ is bounded from countable additivity we have that $$\nu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(A_n) \le \nu(X) < \infty.$$

Thus from Borel-Cantelli $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(A_n) < \infty \implies  \nu(\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n) =0.$$

Now I also have that $$\nu(\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n) \ge  \limsup_{n\to \infty} \nu(A_n)$$ which implies that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty} \nu(A_n) = 0.$$

How can I deduce from here that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \nu(A_n) =0$? It seems I would need to use the fact that $$0 =\limsup_{n\to \infty} \nu(A_n)  \ge \liminf_{n\to \infty} \nu(A_n) \ge 0$$ so $\liminf_{n \to \infty} \nu(A_n) = 0$ also and this would imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \nu(A_n) =0$ because of?

Comment: If the series $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n\to0$.

Comment: A sequence converges if and only if its limit superior is equal to its limit inferior and then the limit is equal to their value as well. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating things. Just because you need to prove a statement about measure theory doesn't mean you have to only throw measure theory at it. Forget Borel-Cantelli and $\limsup$, just focus on what is in front of you.

> Since $X$ is bounded from countable additivity we have that
> $$\nu(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(A_n) \le
>  \nu(X) < \infty.$$

Yes, and that is all you need from measure theory.

Basically, what you now proved is that for $a_n=\nu(A_n)$, you know that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges.

What the statement you are trying to prove says is that the sequence $a_n$ converges. You don't need any measure theory to prove that. It's plain old first-year calculus.

Comment: From the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \nu(A_n)$ I only have that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=N}^\infty \nu(A_n) = 0$, but why would this imply that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \nu(A_n) = 0$?

Comment: @DamonVultra Because $0\le\nu(A_N)\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty \nu(A_n)$ .

Comment: @DamonVultra From calculus, we know that if $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converges, then the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$ must be equal to $0$.